# How could I configure firefox to go to previous page like IE does when I hit Backspace?

Tags: firefox, internet-explorer

Same as title but with sweet feature :

How could I configure firefox to go to previous page like IE does when I hit <kbd>Backspace</kbd>?

### Edit

Right-now, I'm using Firefox on Linux (Fedora13) :

Mozilla/5.0 (X11; U; Linux i686; en-US; rv:1.9.2.12) Gecko/20101027 Fedora/3.6.12-1.fc13 Firefox/3.6.12

But on my laptop (Windows-7 home edition) I remembered that it doesn't work too. I'll retry it later...

Comment: Hmmm... Works for me, and as far as I know I did not change anything in the configuration to make Backspace do that.

Comment: It's the default setting in Firefox. Just go to a site and make sure that the text cursor isn't active and press backspace. If it doesn't work, ty setting keyboard shortcuts to default.

Comment: Related: http://superuser.com/questions/134417/why-is-browser-backspace-action-turned-off-by-default-in-firefox-under-linux

Answer (score 3, accepted):

See [How can I disable the Backspace button's “Go Back” functionality in Firefox?](https://superuser.com/questions/62160/how-can-i-disable-the-backspace-buttons-go-back-functionality-in-firefox) to revert this, like by setting [Browser.backspace_action](http://kb.mozillazine.org/Browser.backspace%5Faction).

(Note though that it can be very annoying if you're editing text but Firefox [doesn't recognize that](http://hints.macworld.com/article.php?story=20090118145518767), and discards your edits... Alternatively, get used to a safer way to go back, like by pressing Alt-Left Arrow.)